# can't remove first element from jcombobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I cannot remove the first element from jcombobox. my code is as follows,

```
JComboBox cBox= cBox= new JComboBox();
...    
while (cBox.getItemCount() > 0)
  cBox.removeItemAt(0);
```

For a test run, i had 3 items in the cBox. When it gets to removeItemAt(0), the debug goes haywire going in to some File access code which is absolutely not related.  Does this twice then gets the below exception. I tried removeAllItems() which directly gets the same exception. However, removeItem(1) works as it should until theres only 1 element left. The exception doesn't crash the app and i can see no items in the combobox after so it worked a little. What exactly am i doing wrong.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at util.Gui$4.actionPerformed(Gui.java:111)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.removeElementAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.removeItemAt(Unknown Source)
at util.Gui.prepareSubLists(Gui.java:164)
at util.Gui$3.actionPerformed(Gui.java:97)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$1.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: It would be useful if you put your actual code here. It could be the while condition as mre says, or any other issues causing NPE somewhere!

Comment: the problem is in the code you are not showing, see the first line of your stacktrace: `at util.Gui$4.actionPerformed(Gui.java:111)`

Comment: i had to add a single blank item then delete the rest. It seems incapable of delet all items from the combobox items.

Comment: again: most probably the problem is _not_ in removing items (whatever they are, default combo is tested well enough - used by legions of developers for 15+ should guarantee that, do we agree?). Instead something is wrong in Gui.java, line 111. Don't add random hacks, dig down to and understand the reason ...

Comment: the removeItemAt(0) also triggers the event actionPerformed() and sometimes user put code here which refers to items which unfortunately have been deleted a few miliseconds before. See more detailed anser below @kleopatra

Answer (score 1):

Isn't your conditional statement wrong? Replace `while` with `if`, as such

```
if(cBox.getItemCount() > 0){
  cBox.removeItemAt(0);
}
```

---

Here's an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org):

```
public final class JComboBoxDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();             
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI(){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JComboBox Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(JComboPane.newInstance());
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(250, 100)); // for demonstration purposes only
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static final class JComboPane extends JPanel{
        private JComboPane(){
            super();
            setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            JCenteredComboBox comboBox = JCenteredComboBox.newInstance();
            JCenteredButton button = JCenteredButton.newInstance(comboBox);
            add(comboBox);
            add(button);
        }

        public static final JComboPane newInstance(){
            return new JComboPane();
        }

        private static final class JCenteredComboBox extends JComboBox{
            private JCenteredComboBox(){
                super(new String[]{"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"});
                setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            }

            public static final JCenteredComboBox newInstance(){
                return new JCenteredComboBox();
            }
        }

        private static final class JCenteredButton extends JButton{
            private JCenteredButton(final JComboBox comboBox){
                super("Remove First Item");
                setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
                addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if(comboBox.getItemCount() > 0){
                            comboBox.removeItemAt(0); // your logic
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            public static final JCenteredButton newInstance(final JComboBox comboBox){
                return new JCenteredButton(comboBox);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

When you run this, pressing the `JButton` will remove the first item in the `JComboBox`. You can keep pressing this until it is empty.

Comment: can't see anything wrong in the while - logic is the same as your if, only repeated. What am I missing?

Comment: @kleopatra, You're right. It looks like OP is essentially performing a "remove all". But that still means that the logic is wrong. The problem is definitely elsewhere. I will remove this answer if OP doesn't update us.

Comment: well your solution works, and i did a little isolated part inside the actual code but that seemed to fail as well. Only thing the app accepts is when i add a blank and then delete the rest. I tried MutableComboBoxModel as well but same result if everything is to be deleted. I will delete all then add bit by bit to see where it blows up:). thanks though

Comment: public void prepareSubLists() throws FileNotFoundException
{ subCategoryList.clear();
 subCategoryList=fileHandler.getSubCategory(kategori.getSelectedItem().toString());     //tested stuff                 MutableComboBoxModel mcbm=(MutableComboBoxModel)cBox.getModel(); int initialSize=cBox.getItemCount(); int breaker=0;  cBox.addItem("");//have to add
while(cBox.getItemCount()>0)
{
Object item = cBox.getItemAt(0);
mcbm.removeElement(item);
++breaker;
if(breaker>=initialSize)
break;
}
if(subCategoryList!=null)
for(int i=0;i<subCategoryList.size();i++)
cBox.addItem(subCategoryList.get(i));
}

Comment: this works. sorry for the mess, but didnt let me reply for 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

This exception may happen because an event is triggered when a combo item is removed and in this event handling method you still refer to combobox items.

For example when you delete somewhere (other than in actionPeformed()) in your code the last item from a combo box with combo.removeItemAt(0) or removeAllItems() then still the event actionPerformed will be fired/executed. But very often the actionPerformed() method contains code to react on user actions (user clicked somewhere on the combobox). So, when the last item has been deleted there is no more item in the combobox and any reference to an item or index in actionPerformed() will cause an exception.

**The solution** to this is to move the code from actionPerformed to e.g. mouseClicked() or another event handler depending on what you want to do.

Comment: no, that doesn't happen in well-behaved code ;-) To make it well-behaved simply always check if an item you want to do something with is still in the model - in _any_ method (including actionPerformed)